# GUI for Asterisk 1.8.8 on Debian 6

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx, freepbx

Can someone point me towards a tutorial for installing either FreePBX, or a Webmin GUI for Asterisk 1.8.8 on Debian 6? Asterisk Thirdlane Multi Tenant PBX Manager and Asterisk Thirdlane PBX Manager are available for Webmin, but I can't find the installation packages and the second seems to be for CentOS. I would actually prefer a Webmin module and a standalone installation of FreePBX, or anything else is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have Asterisk installed, but I'm having trouble with the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend just getting the new FreePBX distro.  If you are set on using FreePBX, it's the best, most stable, best supported way to go.  Otherwise, there are tutorials on http://freepbx.org for installing it from source on debian:

http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/installation/install-process-for-debian

There shouldn't be any reason why you couldn't have both webmin and FreePBX running at once, although I am not familiar enough with webmin to say whether there are any modules that will interface with FPBX.  Below is a link to the download page for FreePBX Distro:

http://www.freepbx.org/freepbx-distro

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I can't use the distro, as I have one server that is capable of being a PBX, at the moment. The server is primarily used for experimentation and it has a bunch of other stuff on it. I can't believe I missed those tutorials. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries; just keep in mind that the experience between the distro and rolling your own is quite different.